# Ask user to re-input a response if it is not a valid response C#

Tags: c#

So I am creating a game that is a command line game in C#, using Visual Studio. What I am wanting to do is ask a question and get the response either 'Y' or 'N'.
I want to be able to have it so that if the response is not either of those, it just repeats the question for them to give a correct response. I am not able to find a good way to do this, as I have not had to do this before. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about a `while` loop? Or a `do...while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to simply re-ask for the response until you get the valid one. A method like this can work for your case:

```
static void GetResponse()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to continue? [Y/N]");

    var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(); //Read a single key from the user. The ReadKey method displays the pressed key on the console.

    //Check the pressed key and if it's not y or n, re-ask for it.
    while (keyInfo.KeyChar.ToString().ToLower() != "y" && keyInfo.KeyChar.ToString().ToLower() != "n")
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Valid choices are: Y or N");
        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(); //Retake the input.

    }
    Console.WriteLine(); //For formatting purposes.
}
```

And then from your Main method, call the GetResponse method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetResponse();
    //Valid response received. Do something here...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple `while` loop:

```
public string GetResponse(string question)
{
    string response = "";

    while(response != "Y" && response != "N")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(question);
        response = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    return response;
}
```

So as long as neither `"Y"` nor `"N"` are entered, the loop keeps running. If the user enters either `"Y"` or `"N"` the loop is left and the value is returned.

Answer (score 1):

you could use enums and TryParse

```
    enum Answers {Yes = 0, No = 1};
    static Answers YesOrNo(string prompt)
    {
        Answers answer;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prompt + " [Yes/No]:");
        } while (! Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), true, out answer));
        return answer;
    }
```

to be used like:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Answer is: " + YesOrNo("Do you want it?"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop until you get a desired answer, which would subsequently break your loop and continue execution

```
string response = String.Empty;
while(response != "Desired Response"){
      //get your response
}
```